# does oracle always throw ora-00060 on deadlock?

Tags: oracle, insert, oracle11g, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Is there any scenario in which Oracle won't throw `ora-00060` (Deadlock detected while waiting for resource) error on deadlock in db?

I have an issue of app freezing on multithreaded record inserts and I wonder what might have caused that
I'm not sure what other relevant information I can provide so please ask in case of any doubts.

Comment: A scenario that *won't* throw ora-00060? Any scenario where a deadlock isn't detected, I guess :) but anyway if your app is freezing, I'd start by looking at the session's wait event(s).

Answer (score 1):

At times I had the felt that Oracle had not thrown deadlock errors for every single time it actually occured. Having said that, if you are experiencing locks with multithreaded inserts, it is more likely that the sessions are temporarily waiting on each other than truly deadlocking.

To find out for sure you can query the v$session paying particular attention to the STATUS, BLOCKING_SESSION, WAIT_CLASS, EVENT, P1TEXT,P2TEXT and P3TEXT. That should paint the picture in terms of sessions holding each other and why. A true deadlock would have session A blocking session B and session B blocking session A, which is relatively rare.

There is also a chance that the application is hanging due to some multithreading mishap, not a database one.

Comment: `At times I had the felt that Oracle had not thrown deadlock errors for every single time it actually occured.` ? Can you throw some light on it technically.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get a chance of getting more information when it happened to a customer. Next time it happens I will use the v$session or gv$session to observe how long two sessions mutually hold each other.